# Remove 'take' from Haskell function

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to Haskell, and am trying to work out how to stop my programs exploding when they hit the end of lists.

As an example, I have a function which mirrors a list of list of chars about the XY axis.

How can I rewrite this without the `take`?

```
mirrorXY' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
mirrorXY' m = (map head m) : mirrorXY' (map tail m)
mirrorXY m = take (length $ m!!0) $ mirrorXY' m
```

P.S. I've just found `transpose`, but I'd still like an answer.

Comment: See also [transpose](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#transpose)

Comment: @Rotsor, I'd already mentioned `transpose` in the question, before you posted your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the empty list, e.g.

```
mirrorXY [] = []
mirrorXY ([]:_) = []
mirrorXY m = (map head m) : mirrorXY (map tail m)
```

That assumes that the lists are of uniform length.

More robustly, something like

```
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (a:_) = Just a

mirrorXY [] = []
mirrorXY m = case mapM safeHead m of
               Nothing -> []
               Just a -> a : mirrorXY (map tail m)
```

which stops on the first list that is too short. Note that this uses `Maybe`s monad instance to do the short-circuiting via the `mapM safeHead m` line.

---

One could even write the last version more compactly, using [`maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amaybe):

```
mirrorXY [] = []
mirrorXY m = maybe [] (: mirrorXY (map tail m)) $ mapM safeHead m
```

But this isn't necessarily clearer.

Answer (score 4):

First, your `mirrorXY'` can be written with higher-order functions `map` and `iterate`  instead of direct recursion:

```
mirr m = map (map head) . iterate (map tail) $ m
```

... and this blows up on hitting the empty list, as you've discovered:

```
*Main> map (map head) . iterate (map tail) $ [[1..4],[2..5],[3..6]]
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Let's try it out without the first part:

```
*Main> iterate (map tail) $ [[1..4],[2..5],[3..6]]
[[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]],[[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]],[
[4],[5],[6]],[[],[],[]],[*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
*Main>
```

So it's easy to fix: we just need to stop on hitting the `[]` in the input list:

```
*Main> takeWhile (not.null.head) . iterate (map tail) $ [[1..4],[2..5],[3..6]]
[[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]],[[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]],[
[4],[5],[6]]]
```

so, the function is

```
mirr xs = map (map head) . takeWhile (not.null.head) . iterate (map tail) $ xs
```

This presupposes that all the sublists are of equal lengths (or at least that the first one is the shortest), but that is easy to fix by tweaking the test in `takeWhile`:

```
mirr xs = map (map head) . takeWhile (all (not.null)) . iterate (map tail) $ xs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the other was understandable.  I think that point-free style is a bit hard for people new to Haskell.

Comment: Yes, I expect that I will be able to read point-free code in a few months.

Comment: @chrisdew for me this isn't a point-free style, but a modular stream-processing style. `iterate` makes a stream of results of repeated function invocation; `map` transforms this stream; we need to stop somewhere - `takeWhile` lets us specify where to stop. This almost reads like English to me at this point, and is easier than actually examining the syntactical intricacies of the code and *recognizing* the concepts, like *iteration* and *mapping*. No laboring to recognize something that's **already named**. And `(.)` is a natural connector for functions - you can read it (as `($)` too) as "of".